# An estimated asymptotic variance

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Let $$
\sqrt{n}(\theta-\hat{\theta}_n) \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{\mathcal{L}} \mathcal{N}( 0,\Sigma),
$$
How to prove that
$$
\sqrt{n}K^T(\theta-\hat{\theta}_n) \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{\mathcal{L}} \mathcal{N}( 0,K^T \Sigma K)?
$$

Comment: What's your definition of convergence in $\mathcal L$ ?

Comment: Convergence in  low

Answer (score 0):

$K^T\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}- \theta)$ is a linear transformation of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}- \theta)$ that you know to converge in distribution to $N(0, \sigma^2)$. Linear transformation preserves the expected value $0$ and changes the variance such that 
$$
K^T\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}- \theta) \xrightarrow{D}K^TN(0,\Sigma)=N(0,K^T\Sigma K),
$$ 
as if $X\sim N (\mu, \Sigma)$, then 
$$
var(AX) =\mathbb{E}[AX-A\mu][AX-A\mu]^T=A\mathbb{E}([X-\mu][X-\mu]^T)A^T=A\Sigma A^T.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much@V.Vancak

Comment: Have$ (\hat{\theta}-\theta)$ and $(\theta-\hat{\theta})$ the same meaning ? just in this case.

Comment: In this case - yes. It doesn't matter which one you take